# How would you convert a "while" iterator into simd instructions?

Tags: c++, while-loop, simd, sse, sse2

This is the code I actually had (for a scalar code) which I've replicated (x4) storing data into simd:

```
waveTable *waveTables[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int waveTableIindex = 0;
    while ((phaseIncrement[i] >= mWaveTables[waveTableIindex].mTopFreq) && (waveTableIindex < kNumWaveTableSlots)) {
        waveTableIindex++;
    }
    waveTables[i] = &mWaveTables[waveTableIindex];
}
```

Its not "faster" at all, of course. How would you do the same with simd, saving cpu? Any tips/starting point?
I'm with SSE2.

**Here's the context of the computation.**
topFreq for each wave table are calculated starting from the max harmonic amounts (x2, due to Nyquist), and multiply for 2 on every wave table (dividing later the number of harmonics available for each table):

```
double topFreq = 1.0 / (maxHarmonic * 2);
while (maxHarmonic) {
    // fill the table in with the needed harmonics
    // ... makeWaveTable() code
    
    // prepare for next table
    topFreq *= 2;
    maxHarmonic >>= 1;
}
```

Than, on processing, for each sample, I need to "catch" the correct wave table to use, due to the osc's freq (i.e. phase increment):

```
freq = clamp(freq, 20.0f, 22050.0f);
phaseIncrement = freq * vSampleTime;
```

so, for example (having vSampleTime = 1/44100, maxHarmonic = 500), 30hz is wavetable 0, 50hz is wavetable 1, and so on

Comment: This is a very small code snippet, and it misses essential details including various relevant definitions. Still it appears that `waveTables` and `phaseIncrement` both have 4 elements. That's unlikely to be big enough to justify SIMD operations. Also, for these kinds of conditional operations you should be looking at AVX-512, which is 5 generations newer than your SSE2 baseline. (skipping SSE3, SSE4, AVX, AVX2)

Comment: @MSalters im within an osc (audio), processed 4 voice per samples, 16 voices, 4x osc. it will do process that snippet often :)

Comment: You have to show more context (i.e., a [mre]). SIMD optimization often starts with choosing appropriate data structures (e.g., SoA instead of AoS).

Comment: Looking at it even further, I also note that the `waveTableIindex < kNumWaveTableSlots` check happens **after** it's used as an array index. That is almost certainly the wrong order. But it shows the complexity of porting such algorithms to SIMD; you need to have the whole picture. A simple fix here would be to set `mWaveTables[last].mTopFreq` to the maximum possible value of `phaseIncrement` (i.e. make it a sentinel).

Comment: It depends mostly on what's inside the while loop, and what kind of condition is being checked, so this isn't a very descriptive title.  e.g. linear search is easy to SIMD, something with a serial dependency on calculations in the previous iteration is usually much harder (unless you can do 4 independent serial dep chains in parallel, possibly with a different data layout to make that work.)

Comment: I've added some details which can help to catch the context. is it more clear now? let me know, else i'll edit further...

Comment: "30hz is wavetable 0, 50hz is wavetable 1" contradicts the `topFreq *= 2;`-line. You did not post a [mre]. It may be possible to explicitly compute the index from the given frequency

Comment: @chtz why contradicts? 30*500=15000 is lower than half samplerate (22050 in this case), so can be choice the first table. 50*500=25000 is above, so second wavetable. And so on, with 2^n step (i.e. topFreq*=2, as stated). I must take the first wavetable which doesn't go over the limit dictated by topFreq, for each table.

Comment: @PeterCordes is the question more clear now? Should I re-edit the title? Linear search?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your values are FP32, I would do it like this. Untested.

```
const __m128 phaseIncrements = _mm_loadu_ps( phaseIncrement );
__m128i indices = _mm_setzero_si128();
__m128i activeIndices = _mm_set1_epi32( -1 );

for( size_t idx = 0; idx < kNumWaveTableSlots; idx++ )
{
    // Broadcast the mTopFreq value into FP32 vector. If you build this for AVX1, will become 1 very fast instruction.
    const __m128 topFreq = _mm_set1_ps( mWaveTables[ idx ].mTopFreq );
    // Compare for phaseIncrements >= topFreq
    const __m128 cmp_f32 = _mm_cmpge_ps( phaseIncrements, topFreq );
    // The following line compiles into no instruction, it's only to please the type checker
    __m128i cmp = _mm_castps_si128( cmp_f32 );
    // Bitwise AND with activeIndices
    cmp = _mm_and_si128( cmp, activeIndices );
    // The following line increments the indices vector by 1, only the lanes where cmp was TRUE
    indices = _mm_sub_epi32( indices, cmp );
    // Update the set of active lane indices
    activeIndices = cmp;
    // The vector may become completely zero, meaning all 4 lanes have encountered at least 1 value where topFreq < phaseIncrements
    if( 0 == _mm_movemask_epi8( activeIndices ) )
        break;
}

// Indices vector keeps 4 32-bit integers
// Each lane contains index of the first table entry less than the corresponding lane of phaseIncrements
// Or maybe kNumWaveTableSlots if not found
```

Comment: 1° question: I can broadcast topFreq when building tables. Would this be even faster? i.e. load single float and broadcast to _m128 is slower than load a _m128 directly, correct?

Comment: @markzzz Without AVX, that `_mm_set1_ps` compiles into `_mm_load_ss` + `_mm_shuffle_ps` https://godbolt.org/z/TP4zvMWMr These shuffles are fast at 1 cycle of latency, and the rest of the code in that function doesn’t use any shuffles. AVX with `_mm_broadcast_ss` is better but not by much. When loading 16-byte vectors, you gonna need to read 4x as many cache lines. Not always the case but I think in this particular one, extra RAM bandwidth is more expensive than two saved instructions (two because the load gonna merge into comparison).

Comment: Thanks. Tried you code, but I don't see any gain rather write "scalar" code as I've posted. Compiler already did some great stuff I guess...

Comment: @markzzz Assuming the profiler tells you the `for` loop in question is what taking the time, one optimization you can try is refactor data structure so the `mTopFreq` values are continuous in memory. This way the `for` loop gonna load from sequential addresses, and once you find all 4 indices, use them to index another pointer with the payload you have in these tables.

Comment: One more thing, if the next code needs scalar indices to compute these pointers, the right way to extract them from the vector is `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` + for non-zero lanes some other instruction to shuffle the vector like `_mm_srli_si128` or `_mm_shuffle_epi32`. Or if you have SSE 4.1 use `_mm_extract_epi32`

Comment: not sure about the suggestion about topFreq refactoring. I can place them continuous in memory such as topFreqs[kNumWaveTableSlots] of course, but why this will speed up things? Should I access to it in different way? Can you show to me an example? Thanks

Comment: @markzzz RAM is a block device these days. Inside CPUs the block size is 64 bytes (cache line), outside the chip often 16 bytes (DDR3 and DDR4 modules deliver 8 bytes per transaction, and well-built computers have dual channel RAM). If you’ll rework to `float topFreqs[kNumWaveTableSlots];` your code gonna need much fewer blocks of memory to complete the loop. Also improves caching, `topFreqs` table has higher chance to fit and stay in L1D cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236137/discussion-between-markzzz-and-soonts).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to write SIMD instructions in C++. A compiler may produce SIMD instructions when appropriate as long as you've configured it to target a CPU that supports such instructions and enabled relevant optimisations. You can use standard algorithms using the `std::execution::unsequenced_policy` to help compiler understand that SIMD is appropriate.

Comment: [Inline assembly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/asm) is another option, although it is generally better to rely on compiler optimizations and profiling.

Comment: @Yun: That is almost certainly excessive. SSE intrinsics are a much better choice. Let the compiler deal with register allocations etcetera.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using GCC/G++ or Clang, there is a non-standard language extension for vector extensions. using `__attribute__ ((vector_size (xx)))`. See the GCC manual for details

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions